# How to send a List of model to controller for export in CSV in Mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, post, model

On my view, an user could use some filters (by name, by pc...). He could also export this filtered result in csv. For that, I'm trying to send the current view model to the controller.

**Export method in controller**

```
public FileContentResult DownloadCSV(IEnumerable<AuditPrinters> model)
{

        var sw = new StringWriter();
        sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5}", "Date", "PrinterSrv", "PrinterName", "IsDefault", "UserName", "PcName"));
        foreach (var record in model)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5}", record.Date, record.Printers.PrinterSrv, record.Printers.PrinterName, record.PrintersConfigs.IsDefault, record.Users.UserName, record.Pc.PcName));
        }
        return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sw.ToString()), "text/csv", "Report123.csv");
}
```

And my view :

```
@model IEnumerable<BetaWebAuditPrinter.AuditPrinters>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printers.PrinterSrv)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Printers.PrinterName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Users.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Pc.PcName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PrintersConfigs.IsDefault)
        </th>    
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Printers.PrinterSrv)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Printers.PrinterName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Users.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Pc.PcName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayTextFor(modelItem => item.PrintersConfigs.IsDefault)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

I don't uderstand what I should do now... I've read some examples with Post, but need a example to really understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `foreach`. In order for the model binder to bind the posted data to a list, they must be indexed:

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Date)

    <!-- etc -->
}
```

Also, this won't work with your view's model being `IEnumerable`. You'll need to change it to:

```
@model List<BetaWebAuditPrinter.AuditPrinters>
```

Also, FWIW, you'll notice I'm using `Html.EditorFor` above. `Html.DisplayFor` is, well, only for display. If you want a HTML input generated, you should be using `EditorFor`.

**EDIT**

Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're trying to achieve here. If this is merely a filtered view, where the data is read-only (i.e. you don't want to let the user modify any of this data, merely to be able to download it as CSV), then you should be using `DisplayFor`. However, you shouldn't be posting the actual data or creating a link that includes the actual data as part of the query string. Rather, you should simply be passing whatever filters are in place on this filtered view to your `DownloadCSV` action. Then, you'll select the data again from the database based on those filters and create your CSV there.

Comment: Ok... and then for posting the model ? does I need a link like that ? @Html.ActionLink("ExportCSV", "DownloadCSV", "AuditPrinters", new { @model= Model })
?

Comment: No, you need to do an actual POST, using an HTML `form` tag.

Comment: Yes this data is for read only. Your edit solution was my first idea, and it's seems that is the more simple. Il's working now.